# Finite ways to write $1 =\sum_{i=1}^{h}\frac{1}{n_i}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $h\geqslant 1$ an integer. 
Can we show (simply), without using group actions, that

> there exists a finite number of decomposition of the form
>   $\displaystyle 1 =\sum_{i=1}^{h}\frac{1}{n_i}$, with $n_i$ positive
>   integers.

P.S.: With group actions, I got it.

Comment: It would be good if you include your group action proof here.

Comment: Forget about group actions, it was complicated AND wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Show by induction on $h$:

> For any $s$ there is at most a finite number of decompositions of the form $s=\sum_{i=1}^h\frac1{n_i}$ with $n_i$ positive integers.

The claim is trivial for $h=0$.
For the induction step $h-1\to h$, note that for any decomposition $s=\sum_{i=1}^h\frac1{n_i}$ we may assume wlog. that $n_h=\min\{n_1,\ldots, n_h\}$. Then $n_h\le\frac hs$, so there are only finitely many choices for $n_h$ and for each choice of $n_h$ there are only finitely many deompositions $s-\frac1{n_h}=\sum_{i=1}^{h-1}\frac1{n_i}$.

Comment: Should be $n_h\leq\frac{h}{s}$, I think.

Comment: Thanks Hagen, simple indeed, it is $n_h\leq \frac{h}{s}$, but the rest follows.

Comment: @user84673 Oops, my bad - I'd still be interesting in reading a group action proof.